# How can I add auto messaging in facebook?

Tags: facebook

I want to create auto messaging for facebook messenger. Someone told me that you can do this but how?
Any suggesstions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this. This is called **Facebook Chat Bot**!

See this [Doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook now allows you to connect bots with your pages. So when a user contacts a page via chat, the bot can respond without waiting for actual human intervention.

The following articles highlights some current applications of these bots.

1. https://www.forbes.com/sites/markfidelman/2016/05/19/10-facebook-messenger-bots-you-need-to-try-right-now/#5b33c350325a
2. https://chatbottle.co/

The bots are simple web applications which will be called by Facebook when a user sends messages.

Details on implementation can be found at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform .